# Can the CIA hack my iphone if I have the latest firmware installed?

Tags: iphone, hacking

I've been watching the news lately about these WikiLeaks about the CIA. Can the CIA hack my iPhone with the latest iOS version installed? How do they do this if my iOS is a closed system and Apple has to verify all software that is installed?

Answer (score 1):

The iOS hacks are specifically tied to jailbroken phones and phones running old software. If your phone is up-to-date, then you ought to be relatively safe from your phone being compromised remotely.  Read here for more info: http://bgr.com/2017/03/08/cia-iphone-hack-wikileaks-vault-7/

Answer (score 1):

Apple said it patched "many" of the cited vulnerabilities in the previous update.

From [CNET](https://www.cnet.com/news/apple-cia-wikileaks-vault-7-ios-patches-vulnerabilities/):

> "While our initial analysis indicates that many of the issues leaked
> today were already patched in the latest iOS, we will continue work to
> rapidly address any identified vulnerabilities," an Apple spokesman
> said in a statement.
>
> Apple said 80 percent of its users are running on the latest operating
> system and are safe from the majority of the CIA's alleged exploits.